# C# - How to not redraw image each time picture box is repainted

Tags: c#, winforms, image, picturebox, repaint

I have a picture box with some images that never need to move. It's for a map designer. The user chooses how many columns and rows the map will have, then it gets drawn as a line grid, and i have a `mouseMove` method because when the user hovers over the edge of a cell it needs to highlight red. So the map is being repainted continuously, very fast, when the mouse is moving. This was no issue when i just had `drawLines` on the map for rows and columns. But now that i just added a cell background image, the cell background images flicker on mouse move as they are being redrawn too fast.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Look for "double buffering". That should eliminate flickering or tearing, although a smarter algorithm itself could reduce the area redrawn ..

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't reduce it on mouse move. A smarter algorithm is required.

Comment: I just thought of having the cell backgrounds in another picture box that only draws when it needs to. Will try that soon when i have time.

Comment: Using double buffering should work independently of the mouse movements by the very nature of how it works - it won't handle the flicker caused by moving on-off-on-off-on-off, but that's a stylistic design issue and not an implementation one. Make sure to *only* update in the paint event and not in the mouse-move event.

Comment: @user2246674 If i don't update in the mouse move event then how will the lines turn red when hovering over them?

Comment: *Queue* a paint event, then wait for it - in C# this can be done with [Control.Invalidate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a). The put the drawing code in [OnPaint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint.aspx) which will be called "shortly" when the control is ready to update.

Comment: @user2246674 I have never done that, so not sure how to approach it. If mouse over line, picturebox.invalidate?

Comment: Call Invalidate when you want to ensure that OnPaint will be called "shortly" - in this case when the mouse changes hover status. Remember that the OnPaint will happen *asynchronously* when the window message loop runs again so the mouse state might actually change several times between OnPaint calls. If drawing is *only* done in OnPaint and double-buffering is enabled, then there should be no flicker or tearing.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Where should i call invalidate? You say the issue is that i have it in moveMove. I don't know where else to put it that makes the lines go red when i hover over them.

Comment: Yes, the mouse move would be appropriate (but only when the state changes such as Over<->NotOver or vice versa).

Comment: @user2246674 Ok i think you have solved this problem. Awesome. I have to go now but will have a try when i get back. Thanks.

Comment: @user2246674 on second thought, in your solution it will still flicker while moving the mouse across a line of the map, because invalidate will be called just as fast as now while that is happening. Not the full solution. I will look into a second picturebox